# Is the following probabilistic identity true?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_t)_t$ be a continuous time Markov process and $ T $ be an almost surely finite stopping time relative to the natural filtration of $(X_t)_t$.

Is the following statement true?

$$ E (X_T | T) = E (X_t) \vert_{t=T}. $$

If so, how does one prove it?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any further assumption on $X$? Discrete-time, continuous-time?

Comment: continuous time, markov, the stopping time is finite almost surely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general this is not true. Consider for example a Brownian motion $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and the stopping time

$$T := \inf\{t \geq 0; X_t=1\}.$$

Since $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, we have $X_T=1$ and therefore

$$\mathbb{E}(X_T \mid T) = 1.$$

On the other hand, $f(t)= \mathbb{E}X_t=0$. Consequently, the equality

$$\mathbb{E}(X_T \mid T) = f(T)$$

does not hold.

Comment: It's a little unclear if OP means $f(T)$ as in $T=T$ is fixed, or $T$ is still the stopping time random variable. It would be true in the latter case, no?

Comment: @AlexR. Well, the question says "[...] $T$ an [...] almost surely finite stopping time". So $T$ is a stopping time and not fixed, as far as I can tell. (If $T$ is fixed, there is actually nothing to prove.)

Comment: @saz, It was a nice counter-example. Here one may ask a question that under adding what condition(s) on $(X_t)_t$ we can show such claim. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi No, I've no idea, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, I made a stupid mistake in how I wrote the question.  It has been corrected accordingly.

Comment: @Frank I don't get it. What do you mean by $\mathbb{E}(X_t)|_T$? (Or asked the other way round: What's the difference to the question you asked before?)

Comment: sorry it should have read "$ t=T $". I have corrected this noe. what I wrote before was equivalent to $ E (X_T) $.

Comment: @Frank I see. Nevertheless the given counterexample answers your question, right?

Comment: true, it does. many thanks